# \BVerbatimInput and \adjustbox : the information is cut at the end of the first page

Tags: verbatim, input, fancyvrb, adjustbox

`\VerbatimInput` calls a `test.dat` file, and produces the following output, where the long lines are not entirely seen:

[image]

A solution for this is use `\BVerbatimInput` together with `\begin{adjustbox}`. This solves the long lines. However, the information of `test.dat` shown is cut at the end of the first page:

[image]

Is there a way to make the rest of the content of `test.dat` to be shown in the following pages ?

The code that produces these two examples:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}

  \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{adjustbox}
  \usepackage{fancyvrb}
  \usepackage{color,soul}
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


  \begin{document}

  \section{VerbatimInput}

  \RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}%
  {fontsize=\footnotesize,
  %
  frame=lines,
  framesep=2em,
  rulecolor=\color{Gray},
  %
  label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
  labelposition=topline,
  }

  \VerbatimInput{./test.dat}


  \clearpage

  \section{BVerbatimInput and adjustbox}

  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
  \RecustomVerbatimCommand{\BVerbatimInput}{BVerbatimInput}%
  {fontsize=\footnotesize,
  %
  frame=lines,
  framesep=2em,
  rulecolor=\color{Gray},
  %
  label=\fbox{\color{Black}test.dat},
  labelposition=topline,
  }

  \BVerbatimInput{./test.dat}
  \end{adjustbox}

  \end{document}
```

The `test.dat` file:

```
 #####l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

 14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:


        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E


     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220     

    14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804       68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 

 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 


 #####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 



 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 

 ####l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg 


      #l.253:
        AL          BL         LC        AA       BB        CC           E
     2.75319    2.75319    2.75319    60.67009  65.70804  68.04220          14.756876   # -> reorientation volumregfddfg
```

Comment: With the `verbatimbox` package, you could use `\verbfilenobox[\footnotesize]{test.dat}`.  This will not line break, but will shrink the size of the verbatim font and will page break.

Answer (score 2):

Well `adjustbox` is for *boxes* not multiples pages. The resulting box can't be broken across pages. However, I (the author of `adjustbox`) worked on some keys to break contained paragraphs into multiple boxes which then can be placed on multiple pages. Get a current version of the package (Version v1.0 – 2012/05/21) and check out the `split` and `pagebreak` keys in the manual (section 4.15 *Experimental Keys*). Please note that the page breaking is done by splitting the scaled box and not by doing normal page breaks between lines. This means the last line can be vertically cut into two parts!

I would actually recommend to not use `adjustbox` altogether but to set the font size accordantly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have been studying section 4.15. If you look in the "code that produces these two examples" (in the post), inside the section entitled `\section{BVerbatimInput and adjustbox}`, I am not quite sure how `split` and `pagebreak` keys could be introduced inside the `\BVerbatimInput{./test.dat}` declaration. If you could provide a MWE using the `./test.dat` I would appreciate it enormously. Again, thank you for all your effort.